# What is this animated icon on the recent apps screen

Tags: app-icons, recents-screen

I noticed this animated icon on some of my apps.  Trying to understand what is its purpose.  It appears to be clickable because when I touch it its background changes.  Here is the image. If you know what this is for please also add a reference to doc because I have searched and searched with to luck.

Answers to the comment:

Android 8

Huawei Mate

Only on recent apps screen

Not shown for every app

Shows for some apps

DisplayOver perm is not requested

DisplayOver perm is not used

The icon animates

The icon seems to be clickable

[image]

Comment: Hello Charles. 1) Which Android version and Android device are you using? 2) Do you see this icon only in recent apps/overview screen? 3) Does it show over all app windows or just a few ones? 4) Can you list the apps upon which you saw this icon? 5) Try booting into safe mode and see if icon still shows up. If not, it could be an app using "Display over other apps" permission. You should be able to toggle this permission for apps under Settings -> Apps -> Special app access.

Comment: Guess - you have hidden some apps and this icon is appearing for those apps and clicking it shows /reveals the app content. Please also add before and after clicking how does it look